# iOS: Search bar disappears in view controller with table view

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a problem when I set a UISearchBar in the navigation item of a view controller with a table view. When I am using the swipe gesture to navigate back from a view controller with this setup, but then cancel the gesture, such that the view reappears, the search bar will disappear.

[image]

For this example I created a new project where I set the navigation in a storyboard and only assign the search controller in `viewDidLoad` of the pushed view controller.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159111/1142743

Comment: Thank you but that is not my problem. I'm fine with the search bar not appearing on my view. My problem is that the second time I cancel the navigation gesture, the search bar somehow is lost and will never be visible again.