# How to make search bar visible? - Search bar is not visible if the collection view is not scrollable

Tags: ios, swift

I have the search bar which is setup using the following code

```
// https://www.raywenderlich.com/4363809-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started
// https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/displaying_searchable_content_by_using_a_search_controller
private lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
    let searchedResultVC = SearchedResultViewController.instanceFromNib()
    
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchedResultVC)
    
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "search_todos".localized
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    return searchController
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...
    
    if navigationItem.searchController == nil {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
}
```

---

It will have the following different behavior based on the status of the collection view.

### Empty collection view - Search bar always visible

[image]

---

### Collection view with lot of content - Search bar visible after scrolling

[image]

---

However, if there is little content inside the collection view and the collection view is not scrollable, then the search bar is not visible.

### Collection view with little content - Search bar always hidden

[image]

Is this the correct behavior? How can I make the search bar visible when I want to perform a search?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/34723301/5133585 answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Set 'hidesWhenScrolling' to true to hide the search bar when there is not enough data to fill the entire screen.

```
searchController.hidesWhenScrolling = true
```